# Video green flickering after merging videos & photos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android

I would like to merge few photos (`.jpg` or `.png`) with movies (mainly in `.mp4`) and store final output as movie (in `.mp4`)

**Duration**

Default duration for photo - 6 seconds

Default video duration - no changes (as original file)

**Sound**

On photo - no sound.

On video - original sound  (as in original file)

**FPS**

FPS (`framerate`) for photos are not important. I know the lowest value is `6`. For me can be `6` or `24`.  FPS for videos should be as it is (without any changes).

All of the files can have different sizes (eg, `500x100` + `1024+2028` + `360x480`). I thing that output should unified somehow (e.g. to `1920×1080` with stretching rest of them but feeping ratio)

**As dependencies I am using**

https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android

**Tested on**

Samsung Note 8 (Android 9) and simulators

**Command:**

```
-loop 1 -framerate 6 -t 6 -i <PATH>/<IMAGE>.png 
-i <PATH>/<VIDEO>.mp4 
-loop 1 -framerate 6 -t 6 -i <PATH>/<IMAGE>.jpg 
-loop 1 -framerate 6 -t 6 -i <PATH>/<IMAGE>.jpg 
-filter_complex 
[0:v]scale=1920:-2,format=yuv420p[v0];
[1:v]scale=1920:-2,format=yuv420p[v1];
[2:v]scale=1920:-2,format=yuv420p[v2];
[3:v]scale=1920:-2,format=yuv420p[v3];
[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:unsafe=1[v] 
-map [v] 
-preset superfast 
-crf 20 
-r 24 
-c:v libx264 
-movflags +faststart 
<OUTPUT>/<VIDEO>.mp4 
-y
```

I tried also:

- with or without `-r 24`
- with or without `movflags`
- with differents `-preset`s
- with differents `-crf`s

But effect is that same.

**Result**

- Video is created (with proper size, ratio & duration).
- I can play video in default (native) or external android video player (e.g. VLC).
- I can not share e.g. to Instagram - it does NOT work.

**Effect**

[image]

**Full console log**
(without `debug` option)

```
ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from '<IMAGE>.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 483x875, 6 fps, 6 tbr, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '<MOVIE>.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-10-15T23:40:52.000000Z
    com.android.version: 9
  Duration: 00:00:01.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 16336 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 16080 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 27.93 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-10-15T23:40:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 256 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-10-15T23:40:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #2, image2, from '<MOVIE>.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 26989 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1429x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1429:2160], 6 fps, 6 tbr, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
Input #3, image2, from '<MOVIE>.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.17, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 28343 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1472x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 92:135], 6 fps, 6 tbr, 6 tbn, 6 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> scale
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0xe8c27000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0xe8c5c000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_concat_8 @ 0xf29c29c0] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1920x3414, SAR 5121:5120) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x3478, SAR 5121:5120)
[Parsed_concat_8 @ 0xf29c29c0] Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 1920x2902, SAR 2073479:2073600) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x3478, SAR 5121:5120)
[Parsed_concat_8 @ 0xf29c29c0] Input link in3:v0 parameters (size 1920x2818, SAR 32407:32400) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1920x3478, SAR 5121:5120)
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] using SAR=4096/4095
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] profile High, level 5.1
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] 264 - core 152 r2851M ba24899 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x3 me=dia subme=1 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=24 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=20.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 pb_ratio=1.30 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '<MOVIE>.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x3478 [SAR 5121:5120 DAR 15363:27824], q=-1--1, 24 fps, 12288 tbn, 24 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    8 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=6 drop=0 speed=   0x    
frame=   20 fps= 15 q=19.0 size=     512kB time=-00:00:00.08 bitrate=N/A dup=15 drop=0 speed=N/A    
frame=   32 fps= 17 q=14.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=10065.3kbits/s dup=24 drop=0 speed=0.215x    
frame=   40 fps= 16 q=13.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:00.75 bitrate=8388.2kbits/s dup=30 drop=0 speed=0.301x    
frame=   52 fps= 17 q=12.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:01.25 bitrate=8388.4kbits/s dup=39 drop=0 speed=0.402x    
frame=   64 fps= 18 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:01.75 bitrate=7190.1kbits/s dup=48 drop=0 speed=0.484x    
frame=   76 fps= 18 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:02.25 bitrate=5592.4kbits/s dup=57 drop=0 speed=0.546x    
frame=   92 fps= 19 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:02.91 bitrate=4314.2kbits/s dup=69 drop=0 speed=0.615x    
frame=  108 fps= 19 q=12.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:03.58 bitrate=4096.8kbits/s dup=81 drop=0 speed=0.641x    
frame=  124 fps= 20 q=12.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:04.25 bitrate=3454.2kbits/s dup=93 drop=0 speed=0.677x    
frame=  136 fps= 20 q=12.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:04.75 bitrate=3090.6kbits/s dup=102 drop=0 speed=0.693x    
frame=  148 fps= 20 q=12.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:05.25 bitrate=3195.7kbits/s dup=111 drop=0 speed=0.709x    
Past duration 2.702934 too large
Past duration 2.903450 too large
Past duration 3.103981 too large
frame=  154 fps= 19 q=17.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=3050.4kbits/s dup=113 drop=0 speed=0.689x    
Past duration 3.304787 too large
Past duration 3.505577 too large
Past duration 3.706123 too large
Past duration 3.906654 too large
frame=  160 fps= 19 q=19.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:05.75 bitrate=2917.8kbits/s dup=113 drop=0 speed=0.67x    
frame=  164 fps= 18 q=20.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:05.91 bitrate=4962.3kbits/s dup=113 drop=1 speed=0.647x    
frame=  167 fps= 17 q=20.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:06.04 bitrate=4859.6kbits/s dup=113 drop=1 speed=0.624x    
frame=  168 fps= 16 q=20.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:06.08 bitrate=6550.0kbits/s dup=113 drop=2 speed=0.593x    
frame=  171 fps= 16 q=20.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:06.20 bitrate=6755.9kbits/s dup=113 drop=2 speed=0.567x    
frame=  175 fps= 15 q=20.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:06.37 bitrate=8553.0kbits/s dup=113 drop=3 speed=0.553x    
frame=  179 fps= 15 q=20.0 size=    7680kB time=00:00:06.54 bitrate=9617.5kbits/s dup=113 drop=4 speed=0.543x    
frame=  181 fps= 14 q=20.0 size=    8192kB time=00:00:06.62 bitrate=10129.6kbits/s dup=113 drop=5 speed=0.527x    
frame=  183 fps= 14 q=20.0 size=    8704kB time=00:00:06.70 bitrate=10629.0kbits/s dup=113 drop=5 speed=0.511x    
frame=  187 fps= 14 q=20.0 size=    9728kB time=00:00:06.87 bitrate=11591.5kbits/s dup=113 drop=6 speed= 0.5x    
Past duration 1.269432 too large
frame=  195 fps= 14 q=20.0 size=   12032kB time=00:00:07.20 bitrate=13673.8kbits/s dup=118 drop=7 speed=0.502x    
frame=  203 fps= 13 q=19.0 size=   14080kB time=00:00:07.54 bitrate=15294.0kbits/s dup=124 drop=7 speed=0.501x    
frame=  211 fps= 14 q=16.0 size=   15872kB time=00:00:07.87 bitrate=16510.8kbits/s dup=130 drop=7 speed=0.504x    
frame=  223 fps= 14 q=14.0 size=   16128kB time=00:00:08.37 bitrate=15775.5kbits/s dup=139 drop=7 speed=0.517x    
frame=  235 fps= 14 q=14.0 size=   16896kB time=00:00:08.87 bitrate=15595.6kbits/s dup=148 drop=7 speed=0.527x    
frame=  247 fps= 14 q=18.0 size=   17408kB time=00:00:09.37 bitrate=15211.3kbits/s dup=157 drop=7 speed=0.535x    
frame=  259 fps= 14 q=18.0 size=   17664kB time=00:00:09.87 bitrate=14653.4kbits/s dup=166 drop=7 speed=0.545x    
frame=  271 fps= 15 q=19.0 size=   18176kB time=00:00:10.37 bitrate=14351.5kbits/s dup=175 drop=7 speed=0.556x    
frame=  283 fps= 15 q=18.0 size=   18688kB time=00:00:10.87 bitrate=14077.4kbits/s dup=184 drop=7 speed=0.566x    
frame=  295 fps= 15 q=19.0 size=   19200kB time=00:00:11.37 bitrate=13827.3kbits/s dup=193 drop=7 speed=0.573x    
frame=  307 fps= 15 q=18.0 size=   19712kB time=00:00:11.87 bitrate=13598.3kbits/s dup=202 drop=7 speed=0.58x    
frame=  319 fps= 15 q=19.0 size=   20224kB time=00:00:12.37 bitrate=13387.8kbits/s dup=211 drop=7 speed=0.588x    
frame=  331 fps= 15 q=18.0 size=   20736kB time=00:00:12.87 bitrate=13193.7kbits/s dup=220 drop=7 speed=0.595x    
frame=  343 fps= 15 q=21.0 size=   21248kB time=00:00:13.37 bitrate=13014.1kbits/s dup=229 drop=7 speed=0.603x    
frame=  355 fps= 16 q=19.0 size=   22528kB time=00:00:13.87 bitrate=13300.8kbits/s dup=238 drop=7 speed=0.609x    
frame=  367 fps= 16 q=19.0 size=   23040kB time=00:00:14.37 bitrate=13129.9kbits/s dup=247 drop=7 speed=0.616x    
frame=  379 fps= 16 q=18.0 size=   23296kB time=00:00:14.87 bitrate=12829.6kbits/s dup=256 drop=7 speed=0.622x    
frame=  391 fps= 16 q=19.0 size=   24064kB time=00:00:15.37 bitrate=12821.6kbits/s dup=265 drop=7 speed=0.628x    
frame=  403 fps= 16 q=18.0 size=   24320kB time=00:00:15.87 bitrate=12549.8kbits/s dup=274 drop=7 speed=0.634x    
frame=  415 fps= 16 q=19.0 size=   24832kB time=00:00:16.37 bitrate=12422.8kbits/s dup=283 drop=7 speed=0.64x    
frame=  427 fps= 16 q=18.0 size=   25344kB time=00:00:16.87 bitrate=12303.3kbits/s dup=292 drop=7 speed=0.646x    
frame=  439 fps= 16 q=19.0 size=   25856kB time=00:00:17.37 bitrate=12190.6kbits/s dup=301 drop=7 speed=0.65x    
frame=  451 fps= 17 q=18.0 size=   26112kB time=00:00:17.87 bitrate=11966.9kbits/s dup=310 drop=7 speed=0.656x    
frame=  463 fps= 17 q=19.0 size=   26880kB time=00:00:18.37 bitrate=11983.7kbits/s dup=319 drop=7 speed=0.661x    
frame=  471 fps= 17 q=19.0 size=   27136kB time=00:00:18.70 bitrate=11882.3kbits/s dup=325 drop=7 speed=0.66x    
[mp4 @ 0xf29bea00] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file
frame=  471 fps= 16 q=-1.0 Lsize=   27880kB time=00:00:19.50 bitrate=11712.5kbits/s dup=325 drop=7 speed=0.678x    
video:27874kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.023015%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] frame I:6     Avg QP: 7.62  size:1001547
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] frame P:143   Avg QP:11.39  size:151068
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] frame B:322   Avg QP:13.28  size:  2888
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] consecutive B-frames:  8.3%  0.8%  2.5% 88.3%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] mb I  I16..4: 12.0% 33.8% 54.2%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] mb P  I16..4:  2.2% 10.0%  4.9%  P16..4: 18.5%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:64.5%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.5%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 2.3%  skip:96.0%  L0:20.0% L1:78.9% BI: 1.1%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] 8x8 transform intra:53.8% inter:28.3%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 77.4% 56.2% 31.9% inter: 3.7% 4.3% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 37% 24% 29% 10%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 16% 28%  4%  9%  6%  6%  5%  8%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 18% 25%  4%  9%  5%  6%  5%  7%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 20% 24% 11%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:11.2% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf29eed00] kb/s:11635.01
```

Merging works properly. All of the elements has correct length. But main problem is "green" (or sometimes 'pink') flickering at the bottom of the movie (exists almost whole movie, with same height all the time)

And how can I add silence to the photos but leave voice from videos.

Comment: Reduce the final resolution and check.

Comment: You are right @Gyan! I changed to `scale=1280:800` and it works properly - there is no green flickering. So when input materials (videos or photos) are too small I have to reduce final movie size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -t 0.1 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=44100 \
-loop 1 -framerate 1 -t 6 -i v1.jpg \
-i video.mp4 \
-loop 1 -framerate 1 -t 6 -i v3.jpg \
-loop 1 -framerate 1 -t 6 -i v4.jpg \
-filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1920:1080,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v1];
 [2:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1920:1080,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v2];
 [3:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1920:1080,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v3];
 [4:v]scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1920:1080,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p[v4];
 [v1][0][v2][2:a][v3][0][v4][0]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset superfast -crf 20 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

- [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) creates silent filler audio for image inputs. A very short duration is set because the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter will automatically pad it to fit the segment duration.
- `-framerate` is set to `1`. The frame rate is increased later with the [fps](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) filter because it can be faster than to initially set `-framerate 24`.
- If you would rather letterbox/pillarbox than crop then use `scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=24,format=yuv420p` instead.